# Values repeating in the hash map unnecessarily

Tags: java, hashmap, repeat

Main computation:

```
for (String keyElement : mKeys) {

            int index = str_mFormatedString.indexOf(keyElement);
            sendTheDataToMap(keyElement, page, index);

            while (index >= 0) {  // indexOf returns -1 if no match found
                index = str_mFormatedString.indexOf(keyElement, index + 1);


                if (index >= 0) {
                    sendTheDataToMap(keyElement, page, index);
                }
            }
        }
```

sendDataToMap function:

```
private void sendTheDataToMap(String key, int page, int index) {
    Pair mPair = new Pair(page, index);
    map.putIfAbsent(key, new ArrayList<>());
    map.get(key).add(mPair);
    //  System.out.println("Entry added to the map....");
}
```

Readmap function:

```
 private void readMap() {
    for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<Pair<Integer, Integer>>> ee : map.entrySet()) {
        String key = ee.getKey();
        ArrayList<Pair<Integer, Integer>> values = ee.getValue();
        // Process the values

        System.out.print(key + " | ");
        for (Pair value : values)
            System.out.print(" " + value.getPage() + "." + value.getIndex());
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Approach is simple, I read the multiple indices of a key from string and add it in to the map with `String,ArrayList<Pair<Integer, Integer>>`.
I know I have done some small mistake either in main computation or while reading the map that is resulting in duplication of values.

Example output:

> can |  5.167 5.223 **5.167 5.223** 7.157 7.338 7.751 **7.157 7.338 7.751 7.157 7.338 7.751** 15.558 16.209 16.436

Highlighted is repeating part.

> **Point is, I don't wanna write multiple values at first place and if that's not happening here then I don't wanna read multiple values.**

Any help?

**Edit 1:**
Inputs: A string (basically any string) which is being slipt on space.
For ex: Hello how are you? => ['Hello','how','are','you?']

One line before Main computation:

```
 mKeys = splitTextToArray(str_mFormatedString);
```

and the function splitTextToArray()

```
private ArrayList<String> splittingTextToArray(String formattedTextInput) {
    String[] tempKeys = formattedTextInput.split("\\s+");

    //convert to Arraylist
    ArrayList<String> mKeys = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(tempKeys));
    return mKeys;
}
```

Comment: ...........[mcve]?

Comment: Please read the code and caption below, it's simple to understand.

Comment: As below, just use a Set.  An ArrayList does not restrict to unique values

Comment: No, it's not simple at all. We have no indication of a problem other than the fact that you're not happy with the output. If you showed some sample input and explained your process we can try to identify a possible problem with your code.

Comment: I'll edit the question with inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `Set` instead of a `List` for your map values to avoid duplicates:

```
Map<String, Set<Pair<Integer, Integer>>> map = new HashMap<>();
// ...
map.putIfAbsent(key, new HashSet<>()); // Or LinkedHashSet to preserve insertion order
map.get(key).add(mPair);
```

If you're really hell-bent on using a list, check whether the list doesn't already contain the value before adding it:

```
Map<String, List<Pair<Integer, Integer>>> map = new HashMap<>();
// ...
map.putIfAbsent(key, new ArrayList<>());

if (!map.get(key).contains(mPair)) {
    map.get(key).add(mPair);
}

// probably should optimize this to get rid of the multiple calls to map.get(key)
```

Have to make sure that `equals()` and `hashCode()` are correctly implemented for your `Pair` class though.

Comment: I can edit the question and paste that here, to my knowledge it's correct. I'll try your answer and reply here

Comment: @AsifAli Don't edit the question with a solution. The question should stand as it is.

Comment: No, I'm not gonna edit it with answer, another person need more explanation about inputs.

Comment: Second method worked, now, I didn't try first. But which one is more optimal, since sendDataToMap is being called in a loop and you have mentioned in the comment about optimization.

Comment: The first one will be more efficient, but note that your results in the set will not be ordered.

Comment: Both worked, choosing first, since i don't need order in my case. **Thanks** you saved my day.

Answer (score 1):

Arraylist can contain duplicate values so you can either use **Set** or check it **before put to arraylist** like below.

1) **Declare Set instead of Arraylist**

```
map.putIfAbsent(key, new HashSet<>());
```

or

2) **check before add in arralist. (for this you need to overwrite hascode and equals in `Pair` Class.)**

```
private void sendTheDataToMap(String key, int page, int index) {
    Pair mPair = new Pair(page, index);
    map.putIfAbsent(key, new ArrayList<>());
  if(!map.get(key).contains(mPair){
    map.get(key).add(mPair);
    //  System.out.println("Entry added to the map....");
  }
}
```